Dask query on dates columns
I am trying to filter a huge dask.DataFrame (~800k lines and 30 cols). I want to use the dask.query function of dask.
start_date = np.datetime64(start_date, 'ns')
end_date = np.datetime64(end_date, 'ns')

query_start = f'BeginObservationDate > {start_date}'
query_end = f'EndObservationDate > {end_date}'

dask_df.query(query_start + ' and ' + query_end).compute()

But I get this error:
SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<unknown>', 1, 8, 
'BeginObservationDate >2024 -0 6 -0 7 T00 :00 :00.000000 and 
EndObservationDate >2025 -0 2 -12 T00 :00 :00.000000))

I don't know what is wrong with my code maybe dask can't compare datetime in queries.
Someone had this trouble before or know how can I fix this ?
Thanks,

maybe first use print(query_start + ' and ' + query_end) to see what you created, Error shows that you created very strange query with 2024 -0 6 -0 7 T00 :00 :00.000000 and it seems it has spaces between values. You may have to format data/time manually like start_date.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")

maybe you should put date/time in " ". OR maybe you could do it without converting to string do it directly - likedf.loc[(df["BeginObservationDate"] > "2024.06.07") & (df["EndObservationDate"] < "2025.02.12")]or maybe evendf.loc[(df["BeginObservationDate"] > start_date) & (df["EndObservationDate"] < end_date)]without usingnp.datetime()`
